# Xamarin PCL consume SOAP web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, soap, xamarin

I have Xamarin Portable Class Library, and I need to connect to SOAP web service. Plan was to communicate with service in portable class, and then access it in iOS, Android, Windows Phone projects. Is this possible? I was able to add web reference in android project, but I can't do that for windows phone. I am using visual studio 2015. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

(FYI: This is off-topic for StackOverflow, but this is a popular question concerning WinPhone, Web services and PCL)

Xamarin has a great tech article that goes over the different web services and how to integrate them into your application (Android, iOS and WinPhone):

> This tutorial introduces how to integrate REST, WCF and SOAP web service technologies with Xamarin mobile applications. It examines various service implementations, evaluates available tools and libraries to integrate them, and provides sample patterns for consuming service data.

[Introduction to Web Services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/)