# xamarin PCL Soap web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am new to Xamarin and C# and SOAP.
I have found similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637119/xamarin-pcl-consume-soap-web-service) and especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959167/xamarin-soap-web-service).
I have a Xamarin PCL project I created on Visual Studio 2017 for Mac, and I need to consume a SOAP web service - WSDL.
I have the same issue as the second link I mentioned, when I add a web reference to the PCL the framework is greyed out and set to WCF and I cant change it to .Net 2.0.
If I Add Web Reference to Android and IOS project then I can change framework.  I am not targeting windows app now, only IOS and android.
Am I doing this correctly by trying to add the web reference to the PCL, or should be be added to the 2 platform projects?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is using the dependency injection as explained below.

Define an interface in the PCL project

```
public interface ISoapServiceHelper
{

    string PerformSyncSoapServiceRequest(string requestXML);
}
```

Implement the interface in the native iOS & Android project as shown below. The requestXML is the SOAP service request

```
public string PerformSyncSoapServiceRequest(string requestXML)
        {
            var ServiceResult = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = CreateSOAPWebRequest();
                XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = createSOAPReqBody(requestXML);
                using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    SOAPReqBody.Save(stream);
                }
                using (WebResponse Serviceres = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return ServiceResult;
        }


public HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest()
        {
            HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"your_URL");
            Req.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
            Req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            Req.Accept = "text/xml";
            Req.Method = "POST";
            Req.Timeout = 20000;
            Req.ReadWriteTimeout = 20000;
            return Req;
        }

        XmlDocument createSOAPReqBody(string requestXML)
        {
            XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();
            SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(requestXML);
            return SOAPReqBody;
        }
```

I am using Unity IOC for dependency injection and it is working fine.